# Why does Datastore produce Timeout while fetching URL?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-flexible

For a short time today, my code running in Flexible Environment "compat" using Google Cloud Datastore API experienced *java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching URL*  on inserting an Item to Datastore in another GAE project.

In addition, Dataflow failed to insert Items at that time; almost certainly the same problem.

This also occurs on simple key queries, so it is not a problem of heavy data.

Before and after this, a lot of other data did get inserted correctly; including a rerun on this same data.

Googling the error suggests it can be caused by downtime in the Google Cloud, but the  Google Cloud Status Dashboard  shows green.

What caused this? How can we avoid it in the future?

```
com.freightos.backup.datastore.gcloudapi.GCloudApiDSBackup$CopyEntities run: ERROR in CopyEntities(commerceDocs/RFQ) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: I/O error at 
com.freightos.backup.datastore.gcloudapi.GCloudApiDSBackup$CopyEntities.retryIfAllowed(GCloudApiDSBackup.java:963) at 
com.freightos.backup.datastore.gcloudapi.GCloudApiDSBackup$CopyEntities.putEntities(GCloudApiDSBackup.java:857) at 
com.freightos.backup.datastore.gcloudapi.GCloudApiDSBackup$CopyEntities.retryIfAllowed(GCloudApiDSBackup.java:959) at 
com.freightos.backup.datastore.gcloudapi.GCloudApiDSBackup$CopyEntities.putEntities(GCloudApiDSBackup.java:857) at 
com.freightos.backup.datastore.gcloudapi.GCloudApiDSBackup$CopyEntities.putEntitiesByParts(GCloudApiDSBackup.java:991) at 
com.freightos.backup.datastore.gcloudapi.GCloudApiDSBackup$CopyEntities.run(GCloudApiDSBackup.java:801) at 
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: I/O error at 
com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.DefaultDatastoreRpc.translate(DefaultDatastoreRpc.java:105) at 
com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.DefaultDatastoreRpc.commit(DefaultDatastoreRpc.java:133) at 
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$4.call(DatastoreImpl.java:390) at 
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$4.call(DatastoreImpl.java:387) at 
com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:179) at 
com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:244) at 
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.commit(DatastoreImpl.java:386) at 
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.commitMutation(DatastoreImpl.java:380) at 
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.put(DatastoreImpl.java:340) at 
com.freightos.backup.datastore.gcloudapi.GCloudApiDSBackup$CopyEntities.putEntities(GCloudApiDSBackup.java:836) ... 9 more Caused by: com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: I/O error, code=UNAVAILABLE at 
com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:126) at 
com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:95) at 
com.google.datastore.v1.client.Datastore.commit(Datastore.java:84) at 
com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.DefaultDatastoreRpc.commit(DefaultDatastoreRpc.java:131) ... 17 more Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching URL: https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/freightos-prod-backup2:commit at 
com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:173) at 
com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:45) at 
com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchRequest.execute(UrlFetchRequest.java:74) at 
com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981) at 
com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:87) ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `UrlFetchTransport` is being used when it shouldn't be.

I've filed [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1492) to fix the `google-cloud-java` library.

In the mean time, you should be able to force it to use `NetHttpTransport` when you construct the `DatastoreOptions` object:

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.auth.http.HttpTransportFactory;

DatastoreOptions.newBuilder()
    .setHttpTransportFactory(new HttpTransportFactory() {
      @Override
      public HttpTransport create() {
        return new NetHttpTransport();
      }
    })
    ...
```

Comment: I am using 

   <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>gcloud-java-datastore</artifactId>
   <version>0.2.8</version>

But apparently these 2 Maven dependencies are needed instead.
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-cloud</artifactId>
   <version>0.8.0</version>
  </dependency>

... and ...
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
   <version>0.6.0</version>
  </dependency>

Is that correct?

Comment: With those libraries, the code compiles. I changed the deprecated methods. (See http://pastebin.com/eZNmYmWw  for formatted code nd stacktrace.)

I get  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.datastore.v1.Entity.getPropertiesMap()Ljava/util/Map; at this code:
QueryResults<Entity> results = datastore.run(query);
while (results.hasNext()) {...

Comment: Is it possible there is an an older version of the `datastore-v1-protos` also on the classpath? The `getPropertiesMap()` method was added in `1.2.0` (so would not be present in `1.0.0` or `1.0.1`).

Comment: Datastore is in use. Shuffling around the dependencies   to avoid that clash gives this error preventing the usage of com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transform.DoFn. "The type com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Comment: It seems an older version of one of the libraries is still ending up on the classpath. You might need to try a `dependencyManagement` section to force the use of `com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.0.0`.

Comment: I succeeded in implementing your setHttpTransportFactory code. Let's assume for now  that it stops the timeout exceptions (of course, given that the exceptions are irregular, we'll just have to see over time if they recur.)